# Did Lord Krishna stop the knowledge of Divya-astras from coming to Kali-yuga?

Tags: krishna, kali-yuga, weapon

Did Lord Krishna stop the knowledge of Divya-astras from coming to kali-yuga?

If yes, please provide the scriptural reference.

Comment: Divya astras  disappeared because the people of kali yuga cannot respect them , treat them or deploy them the way they must be.

Comment: Divya astras are hidden because of the above reasons which @moonstar2001 has stated, also because of the fact that they are waiting to be revealed through Kalki, who is destined to receive those through Parashuram Muni.

Comment: Most of those who had knowledge of Divya Astras died after the Kurukshetra war and after the war Ashwathhama was cursed to forget all his knowledge and thus he can't teach anyone.

Parikshit and Vrishakethu (Son of Karna) were trained by Arjuna. But Krishna asked them not to propagate anymore as in Kaliyug, people will not use them to maintain Dharma but will misuse for personal purposes. So we don't see any students of Vrishakethu. Satyaki died in a quarrel among yadavas.

Comment: Lord Parasurama was now probably in deep penace waiting to be a mentor of Kalki. Arjuna never made any other student like Satyaki after the war. Dritharashtra died in a forest fire without passing knowledge of Astras to anyone. Barbarika's head went dead after the war as his wish was fulfilled to watch the Dharma Yudhha. Lord Shiva Sealed Pasupathastra mantra in Kaliyug to avoid misusing of it.

Comment: There are actually no scriptural verses which speak directly about this, but if one can read between the lines, it is quite helpful

Comment: If a Brahmin who has attained turiya, chant mantras to invoke astra devata, will they arrive to reside in body? Manuscripts of Astra Mantras were apparently found in a nambudiri elder's family.