# Manthra of Asthras

Tags: mantras, weapon

In ancient Indian warfare Sastras and Astras were used. Sastra is a physical weapon that cuts/injures/kills/enemy while an Astra has a *mantra* associated with its use (projection).

What records do we have of some famous mantras for Astras e.g., Brahmastra, Nagastra or Varunastra? Granting that these would have been kept secret even in those times, is there any Vedic book/reference or other source that describes the content and procedure for use of projectiles powered by a mantra meant to be used with an Astra?

Comment: astras are all imginary.  if they were real Hindus would have defended themselves better againt Greeks,Muslims et al.

Comment: There is no power in them, they are all lies?

Comment: "lies" is too strong - they are all poetic imagination.  It took the US billions of dollars to be able to "hit a bullet with a bullet" missile defense,  when you see ancient Hindu warfare as depicted on TV serials - they routinely hit an arrow with an arrow.

Comment: i don't think any Texts will cover these details. They will be known only to the disciples from their Gurus directly.. Like what the Mantra is and how to apply it.. etc..

Comment: Yes, Astra mantras are there in scripture.  But for obvious reasons I won't be posting an answer.

Comment: if anybody things astras are real and is an Indian patriot he should tell the defence ministry.

Comment: As per my knowledge they are sealed so people of kaliyuga could not use them take a look— https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21534/did-lord-krishna-stop-the-knowledge-of-divya-astras-from-coming-to-kali-yuga

Comment: @Keshav Sinivasan Why not give reference if in Kaliyuga anyhow it would not work? After all in this website we are learning close details about Hinduism.

Comment: @Narasimham I don't know of any scriptures that say that Astras are locked in the Kali Yuga.  I think that's just a popular belief.

Comment: By the way why anyone would want to know about this astras. Unless and until to destroy some thing. Gods are clever. They will never reveal such things to kaliyug people. Tons of questions and tons of discussions, but no one will reach the truth. Best of luck to you lol

Comment: @user13155: Either it is there or it is not there No matter what is opinioned..

Answer (score 1):

The most easily available astra is Brahmaastra and the deity is Bagalaamukhii. Her panchanga ( 1)Patala 2) Poojaa Paddhati 3) Kavacham 4) Sahasranaamam and 5) Stotram) is easily available in [Mantramahaarnava](https://archive.org/details/Mantra_Maharnava_Khemraj_Edition),  [Shaaktapramod](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.541555) and [Saankhyaayana Tantra](https://archive.org/details/SankhyayanaTantraGoswamiSriLaxmiNarayanDixit)

Other texts featuring Bagalaamukhii, not so readily available are Jayadratha Yaamala, Ishvaramata Tantra.